# New Storage Plugin for csv , json

Tags: sandbox, mapr, apache-drill

I want to add a new storage plugin ( called onetest)
When I add it on the webUI onetest appear but the directory and files that I had inside "onetest" doesn't appear on my drill explorer.

Note that in montest I placed two csvs.

The JSON I put on the webUI:

```
{
  "type": "file",
  "enabled": true,
  "connection": "maprfs:///",
  "workspaces": {
    "root": {
      "location": "/patrick",
      "writable": false,
      "defaultInputFormat": null
    },
    "montest": {
      "location": "/patrick/test",
      "writable": true,
      "defaultInputFormat": null
    },
    "tmp": {
      "location": "/tmp",
      "writable": true,
      "defaultInputFormat": null
    }
  },
  "formats": {
    "psv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "tbl"
      ],
      "delimiter": "|"
    },
    "csv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "csv"
      ],
      "delimiter": ","
    },
    "tsv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "tsv"
      ],
      "delimiter": "\t"
    },
    "parquet": {
      "type": "parquet"
    },
    "json": {
      "type": "json"
    },
    "maprdb": {
      "type": "maprdb"
    }
  }
}
```

Output in drill explorer:

[image]

The directories has read and write access :

[image]

Do you have any idea?

Best

Comment: Are `onetest.root` & `onetest.montest`  shown in Drill Shell? If no, is `/patrick` right directory & has got proper permissions?

Comment: no that is my problem i don't know why they are not showing :( yes /patrick and /patrick/test with a read and write permission . I added a screenshot on my post

Comment: You mean not showing  in both drill-explorer & drill-shell?

Comment: Yes . what the explorer reflects what is on the shell. basically if i run "show tables" in the shell i don't have onetest.root and onetest.montest . But i have onetest.default and onetest.tmp .

Comment: I am assuming you should be using "Drill for MapR" & running drill on same MapR cluster. onetest is similar to dfs. Right? Add these two directories there & check these are shown or not?

Comment: Yes sorry i mention it on the keywords but not on the post . Yes i am using Drill with MapR sandbox. You are right the only way to see it is to put it as the same directory of the mapr . Thanks man. I thought i could create new folder ...

Comment: You can add and remove  workspaces in `dfs`. Check: http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Connecting+Apache+Drill+to+Data+Sources